# Python or C language for fast writing to MySQL (TCP server)

Tags: mysql

I am developing a simple asynchronous TCP server in VB.net.

The problem is that the app takes too long to write data to the MySQL database. At the moment, I have the app deployed on one server and the database on another Ubuntu server. It takes about 700 ms to execute a query.

I need to develop another app either in Python or C to run on an Ubuntu server. The app is an asynchronous TCP server that receives a string of 160 bytes from each client (with a maximum of 1000 clients), parses the string and write it to the MySQL database.

I need to know what language is better suited for this task, Python or C?

Another requirement of the app is that it needs to make 1000 queries(writes) in 10 seconds.

My server has 16 GB of memory, quadcore Xeon, SSD, Ubuntu server.

Comment: You need to find out why MySQL performs the query so slow. I doubt that rewriting your program would do any good. Ensure it's NOT MySQL being slow on its own before you swap to a different language.

Comment: Hello Again, I think one the problem is the 2 server wasn´t on same location. So the internet speed of course increase the time of query. So I need to change the language to host the app in the same server of mysql. Thanks

Comment: Write it in Python. If performance is not good enough, rewrite it in C.